# Have HyperLink Text in TextView

Tags: android, textview

I want to have few text as hyperlink in my `TextView` like the following image:

[image]

Also, similar to above Image I want the hyperlink to open the respective setting window. How is this possible?

EDIT: Just to make my question more specific, I want to open cellular setting when those text are clicked. So, I don't know what will be the URL for that to use href tag in String object.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: use concept of spannable string onClickSpan(). Hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `SpannableString` for this

```
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("Your string value");
    ClickableSpan clickableTerms = new ClickableSpan() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View textView) {
               // show toast here
         }
      @Override
      public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
           super.updateDrawState(ds);
           ds.setUnderlineText(true);

                }
            };
  ss.setSpan(clickableTerms, 4, 10, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  myTextView.setText(ss);
  myTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
  myTextView.setHighlightColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

You can make multiple words clickable by this method.

Answer (score 3):

Try this with the help of HTML anchor  tag

```
TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setClickable(true);
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String text = "No intenet connection. Make sure that <a href='any url'> Wi-Fi</a> or <a href='any url'> cellular mobile data is turned on</a>, then try again";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: How do I provide URL to open cellular setting?

Comment: You can not call any event in html except javascript function, you can add click listener to textview and can navigate to connection settings.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `autoLink` property of `TextView`

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/YOUR_TEXTVIEW"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="all"
     />
```

And Programatically u can create the hyper link below the text by the help of the `SpannableString` like below example:-

```
 SpannableString styledString
      = new SpannableString("Large\n\n"     // index 0 - 5
           + "Bold\n\n"          // index 7 - 11
           + "Underlined\n\n"    // index 13 - 23
           + "Italic\n\n"        // index 25 - 31
           + "Strikethrough\n\n" // index 33 - 46
           + "Colored\n\n"       // index 48 - 55
           + "Highlighted\n\n"   // index 57 - 68
           + "K Superscript\n\n" // "Superscript" index 72 - 83 
           + "K Subscript\n\n"   // "Subscript" index 87 - 96
           + "Url\n\n"           //  index 98 - 101
           + "Clickable\n\n");   // index 103 - 112

     // make the text twice as large
     styledString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, 5, 0);

     // make text bold
     styledString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 7, 11, 0);

     // underline text
     styledString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 13, 23, 0);

     // make text italic
     styledString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 25, 31, 0);

     styledString.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), 33, 46, 0);

     // change text color
     styledString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 48, 55, 0);

     // highlight text
     styledString.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.CYAN), 57, 68, 0);

     // superscript
     styledString.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 72, 83, 0);
     // make the superscript text smaller
     styledString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f), 72, 83, 0);

     // subscript
     styledString.setSpan(new SubscriptSpan(), 87, 96, 0);
     // make the subscript text smaller
     styledString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f), 87, 96, 0);

     // url
     styledString.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.google.com"), 98, 101, 0);

     // clickable text
     ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View widget) {
    // We display a Toast. You could do anything you want here.
    Toast.makeText(YOUR_CONTEXT, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   }
  };
```

Comment: But how do I put the string with the setting hyperlink?

Comment: What is the purpose of **android:autoLink**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky ..It auto detect the email,http url on the text of the TextView

Comment: I've been looking for this for a graduate project all night. Every other post was some convoluted way of adding underline and changing the color to match a hyperlink. Thanks!

Comment: @NobleUplift WC bro..All the best for your project

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
 yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<bThis is normal text </b>" + "<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">This is cliclable text</a> "));
 yourTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Also you can use `Spannable String` with `Clickable Span`.