# HyperLink in textview inside a scrollview is not clickable

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

```
          <ScrollView
          android:id="@+id/id_scrollview"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:fillViewport="true"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_5sdp">
              <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/id_main"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:gravity="center_vertical"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:background="#ffffff"
                 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                 android:orientation="vertical">
                   <LinearLayout
                      android:id="@+id/id_test"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:gravity="center_vertical"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:background="#ffffff"
                      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                      android:orientation="vertical">

                          <TextView
                          android:id="@+id/id_key_tv"
                          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight=".5"
                          android:text="@string/key_tv"
                          android:textStyle="bold"
                          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                          android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15sdp"/>

                         <TextView
                          android:id="@+id/id_value_tv"
                          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:textSize="15sp"
                          android:background="#ffffff"
                          android:gravity="center_vertical"
                          android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Code snippet for parsing the *url*:

```
Intent showDocumentInBrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
showDocumentInBrowserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(clickedItemInViewSanctioned.getmValue()));
startActivity(showDocumentInBrowserIntent);
```

I am trying to add hyperlink(eg **URL**) to the  `TextView`(id_value_tv),unfortunately the link is not working.

Please can anyone tell me what the problem is here?
Thank You.

Comment: Refer this link :- http://stackoverflow.com/a/42671603/3946958

Comment: @Ramya BA you can use onclick listener.

Comment: Pls post the code where you are setting the text containing a hyperlink to the TextView.

Comment: CustomListRowData  Obj =   new CustomListRowData("Disbrsd File ", File);
                    Obj .setmIsValueHyperLink(true);
                 ArrayList<CustomListRowData> DetailsList  =   new ArrayList<>();
                    DetailsList.add(obj);

Comment: public class CustomListRowData{ private String mKey;
         private String mValue;
         private boolean mIsValueHyperLink;}     //With getters and setters

Comment: And the link works fine if the scroll view is removed

Comment: set your scrollview focus false may be that create problem@ramyaba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

Later I replaced it with

```
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

 final int action = event.getAction();
 if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

     if (fileValue.equals("No File")) {
         showAlert("No file exists.", true);
     } else {
         Intent showDocumentInBrowserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         showDocumentInBrowserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(customListRowDataObj.getmValue()));
         startActivity(showDocumentInBrowserIntent);
     }    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setMovementMethod` like this:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">google</a> "));

myTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      //In  XML
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:id="@+id/titleTxtview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_title_bg"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            custom:typeface="helvetica_bold" />


//In Java

titleTxtview1.setText(Html.fromHtml(EndMessage));
            titleTxtview1.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```